# Pandas DataFrame column concatenation

Tags: python, numpy, merge, pandas, concatenation

I have a pandas Dataframe y with 1 million rows and 5 columns.

```
np.shape(y)  
(1037889, 5)
```

The column values are all 0 or 1. Looks something like this:

```
y.head()  
a, b, c, d, e  
0, 0, 1, 0, 0  
1, 0, 0, 1, 1  
0, 1, 1, 1, 1  
0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

I want a Dataframe with 1 million rows and 1 column.

```
np.shape(y)  
(1037889, )
```

where the column is just the 5 columns concatenated together.

```
New column  
0, 0, 1, 0, 0  
1, 0, 0, 1, 1  
0, 1, 1, 1, 1  
0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

I keep trying different things like `merge`, `concat`, `dstack`, etc...
but can't seem to figure this out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want new column to have all data concatenated to string, it's good case for apply() function:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,0,0], 'b':[0,0,1,0], 'c':[1,0,1,0], 'd':[0,1,1,0], 'c':[0,1,1,0]})
>>> df
   a  b  c  d
0  0  0  0  0
1  1  0  1  1
2  0  1  1  1
3  0  0  0  0
>>> df2 = df.apply(lambda row: ','.join(map(str, row)), axis=1)
>>> df2
0    0,0,0,0
1    1,0,1,1
2    0,1,1,1
3    0,0,0,0
```